# autosize div to contents using jquery on mouseover

Tags: jquery, css, fluid-layout

I have a div that autohides to the left of the screen and contains miller columns. the width of the contents of the div is unknown. if I hard code a width using .width(500) it works fine but now I'm trying to get it to auto-fit to the contents on mouse over, then shrink back down on mouseleave.

this is the code I have at the moment, the problem is, nothing happens when I mouseover. the idea was to remove the css attribute of width, reverting back to the default value

```
$(".leftnavdiv").live({                                          //code for autohide
    mouseenter:
    function () {
        $(this).css('width','');
        //$("body").css('padding-left','510px');
    },
    mouseleave:
    function () {
        $(this).css('width','10px');
        //$("body").css('padding-left','20px');
    }
}
);
```

Comment: Could you post your CSS and HTML - also, it helps a lot if you make an example of what you currently have in http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can play around with it.

Comment: To have an element stretch to width needed you have to set it to `auto`. There are no empty values in CSS – [any property has a default value (initial value). For `width` this is `auto`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Float your container to the left and then set `width: auto;` on mouse over:

```
$(".leftnavdiv").bind("mouseenter", function() {
    $(this).css('width', 'auto');
});

$(".leftnavdiv").bind("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).css('width','10px');
});​
```

Working example: [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aLhHX/)

Comment: Simple and elegant. Works beautifully :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the width to 0, setting it blank makes it to take some random value. check this fiddle and try out for 0 and blank.You can see the difference in the console log.
FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/UyAPj/

```
$(this).css('width','0px');
```